# Rails threads testing db lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

Let's say we want to test that the database is being locked..

```
$transaction = Thread.new  {
    Rails.logger.debug 'transaction process start'
    Inventory.transaction do
      inventory.lock!
      Thread.stop
      inventory.units_available=99
      inventory.save
    end
  }
  $race_condition = Thread.new  {
    Rails.logger.debug 'race_condition process start'
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env].symbolize_keys
    config[:flags] = 65536 | 131072 | Mysql2::Client::FOUND_ROWS
    begin
      connection = Mysql2::Client.new(config)

      $transaction.run
      $transaction.join
    rescue NoMethodError
    ensure
      connection.close if connection
    end
  }
  Rails.logger.debug 'main process start'
  $transaction.join
  Rails.logger.debug 'main process after transaction.join'
  sleep 0.1 while $transaction.status!='sleep' 
  Rails.logger.debug 'main process after sleep'
  $race_condition.join
  Rails.logger.debug 'main process after race_condition.join'
```

In theory, I'd think it would do the transaction thread, then wait( Thread.stop ), then the main process would see that it's sleeping, and start the race condition thread(which will be trying to alter data in the locked table when it actually works).  Then the race condition would continue the transaction thread after it was done.

what's weird is the trace

```
main process start
transaction process start
race_condition process start
```

Coming from nodejs, it seems like threads aren't exactly as user friendly.. though, there has to be a way to get this done.

Is there an easier way to lock the database, then try to change it with a different thread?

Comment: See my answer and rate it if it helped! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

For any resource to make it a "Mutually Exclusive", you need to use **Mutex** class and use a **synchronize** method to make the resources locked while one thread is using them. You have to do something like this:

`semaphore = Mutex.new`

and use it inside the Thread instance.

```
$transaction = Thread.new  { 
  semaphore.synchronize{
  # Do whatever you want with the *your shared resource*
  }
}
```

This way you can prevent any deadlocks.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.new automatically starts the Thread. 
But that does not mean that it is executing.
That depends on Operations system, ruby or jruby, how many cores, etc.

In your example the main thread runs until
$transaction.join, 
and only then your transaction thread starts, just by chance.
It runs still Thread.stop, then your '$race_condition' Thread starts, because both other are blocked (it might have started before)

So that explains your log.

You have two $transaction.join
they wait until the thread exits, but a thread can only exit once...
I don't know what is happen then, maybe the second call waits forever.

For your test, you need some sort of explicit synchronization, so that our race_thread writes exactly when the transaction_thread is in the middle of the transaction. You can do this with Mutex, but better would be some sort of message passing. The following blog post may help:

http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/a-modern-guide-to-threads/